# How to exclude classes and triggers from change set validation

Tags: apex, trigger, class, change-set

I'm validating a change set and getting the code coverage error stating your orgs code coverage is less than 75%
i do not want any apex classes, testclasses, triggeres to be run while validating a change set as my Orgs code coverage is less than minimal.

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Why not get your code coverage up to 75%+? Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: Are you deploying new or updated Apex of any kind?

Comment: no My change set doesn't contain any component which is a class or trigger but still when i click validate its running the already existing(in prod)classes.                                My change set has list views reports, pagelayouts, custom fields and dashboards

Comment: Are you sure your change set doesn't have any apex components?  The documentation states that unit tests will not run if there are no Apex components in the package.  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets_test_levels.htm

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you deploy or validate a change set, you can specify what tests you'd like to run.  There's a quick read about it [here](https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2016/09/07/deployment-options-for-changeset/):

[image]

Since you're not deploying any code changes, the Default or Run local tests options should validate the changeset properly without having to run all the tests in your org.

Comment: Thanks for the post In my case even when i choose the second Option (RUN LOCAL TESTS) its still running the classes and showing the same error. If i use the run Specified tests as well it's not working out as my ORG's code coverage is lessthan minimal